# Where do I see how long my gas mask can hold?

Tags: metro-2033

I'd like to know how much time I have on my gas mask on the surface.

My character's breathing frequency changes sometimes. Is that an indicator that I should change my gas mask?

Also, should I change my gas mask for any other reason than if it becomes damaged, like, glass broken from an attack?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is clear indication of that on [Artyom's watch](http://metro2033.wikia.com/wiki/Artyom%27s_Watch).

On PC, you have to press <kbd>T</kbd> to look at it. On Xbox 360 - Left Bumper.

[image]

> Also, should I change my gas mask for
>   any other reason than if it becomes
>   damaged, like, glass broken from an
>   attack?

AFAIK, new mask always comes with the filter at 100%, so you could change just for that.

Comment: nice. Would you also like to answer the second part of my question?

Answer (score 3):

In the inventory, beneath the gas mask is a number. That's the number of minutes left for your filter. It's game minutes though, not real-time minutes.

Also, when your filter is getting low your mask should start to fog up, which is an indication that you will need to change it soon.